# Fortran: Evaluation of a multiplication in parenthesis

Tags: fortran

In Fortran I have `print *,(4,2)*(2,1)` and the result is `(6.,8.)`. How does this computation is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), an intrinsic type in Fortran since the year .  And you are looking at a complex multiplication.